# Storing&Retrieving Integer in/from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with integers in MySQL. I am trying to update a cell which stores an integer. However, I have problem with the type of that cell. Actually it is type is set to `int` but when I retrive the data I always get 0 and I belive it is because of the problem about how I am trying to get it. Here is my code sample;

```
    function updateNumb($username) {


    $query = "SELECT `num` FROM `profiles` WHERE `nick`='" . $username . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->conn) or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $row['num'] = $row['num'] + 1;
    $numb = (int)$row['num'] + 1;



//here I update the data.

    $query = "UPDATE `profiles` SET `num`=" . $numb . " WHERE `nick`='".$username."'";
    mysql_query($query, $this->conn) or die(mysql_error());

    return $numb;
}
```

Can it be because of mysql_fetch_array stuff? Or how could I overcome this problem?

Comment: what happens if you echo `$numb` right after you added 1? Also you could drop the (int) in front of that line and add it inside your query like `$query = "UPDATE profiles SET num=" . (int)$numb . " WHERE nick='makyol'";` - which I think should also be nick=$username, or not?

Comment: Yes, nick will be $username. After adding one, if I echo the $numb I always get 1 because it always retrieves 0 no matter whatever was inside.

Comment: when you do a `print_r($row);` does the array contain a key named num?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you provided, maybe it's not doing what you really need, for example num is incremented twice, but there are no visible mistakes that would make it return 0, at least not in what we can see.

Make sure you provide valid username, try to echo your query before sending to mysql to see what it really looks like, maybe try this query yourself in mysql client or phpmyadmin to see what's going on.

Also if the only thing you need is to increment num for some user you can do it in one update, you don't need to use select to get that number:

```
UPDATE profiles set num=num+1 WHERE nick='somenick'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I check the username and there was a mistake in username.

Answer (score 1):

replace `partisayisi` with `num`

Comment: yea, I changed it but it is not the exact problem. It is caused because of the change I did before posting it in stackoverflow.